# Kurento package dependencies currently broken

Tags: dependencies, installation, kurento

I install kurento-media-server on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Followed the instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kurento/kurento 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install kurento-server**
```

Get this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kurento-server : Depends: kurento-media-server (= 5.0.2-trusty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When doing a

```
apt-get install kurento-media-server
```

I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kurento-media-server : Depends: kms-core (>= 5.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: kms-elements (>= 5.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: kms-filters (>= 5.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried same instructions on a new instande of ubuntu 14.04 and they worked for me.

There is something weird in your logs because the version it is requesting are quite old, current version of kurento is 5.1.3 but your apt-get is asking for 5.0.2.

Have you got some errors when doing 
`sudo apt-get update` ?

If you try `sudo apt-get install kms-core`, what is the output in this case?